# Reclaim snatched domain name

Tags: domain-registration

I'm looking for options to get back a domain name that just expired and was re-registered by an unknown link farmer.

Between extended holidays, bank and hosting provider's opening hours and me the domain wasn't renewed and was quickly scooped up elsewhere.

1. How can I get hold of the new registrator? (My contact information still appears in the WHOIS databases)
2. Is it possible to appeal to any authority to claim ownership?
3. Is it possible to contact Google about removing the page from the search engines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly,

All of these questions should really be addressed to your domain registrar.

That said:

> `1`. How can I get hold of the new registrator (My contact information
>   still appears in the whois databases)?

If that's true, then it would appear that your domain name was not actually fully expired.  When a domain is expired the old whois information should be purged, and then when it's re-registered by someone else the new details should then be present.

Without knowing at least which TLD it's in (and maybe the whole name) it's hard to guess more.

It's possible that the domain registry has themselves pointed your NS records at their own link farming pages.

> `2`. Is it possible to appeal to any authority to claim ownership?

Talk to your registrar, and if necessary the TLD domain registry.  What they do will depend on the TLD's policies though.

> `3`. Is it possible to contact google about removing the page from the search engines?

No, as far as I know Google will not arbitrate in cases like this - as far as they're concerned the new content is legitimate and there's no reason not to index it.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your answer. The registrar would be the hosting provider I initially used to register? The specific domain name is n2cms.com

Comment: ok, it's ENOM (who are the ICANN registrar) that are running the page now on your domain - as I thought the domain hasn't (as yet) been re-registered to someone else.  Contact your hosting provider and/or ENOM to get the registration back ASAP!

Comment: congrats - I see it's working again :)

Comment: Yeah =) I feel rather noobish. Seeing those affiliate links gave me the wrong idea.

Comment: `"All of these questions should really be addressed to your domain registrar. This is not a programming related question."`

I didn't realize this portion of stackexchange was about programming. I always thought that was what stackoverflow was for.  Seems appropriate to me.  If not here, where?

Comment: @Unipartisandev did you not see the line above where it says "migrated from stackoverflow.com" ?

Comment: Not at first, sorry.  I was really quite confused because I thought I had come to the right place to search for the question I was looking for ;)

Answer (score 4):

If it's a .com domain and it's literally just expired, it's possible the domain is in "Redemption".

This is a last-chance status before the domain is deleted where the domain remains registered for approx 1 month.  In this status it's also very likely the registrar will put pay-per-click adverts in place of your website...

Contact your registrar for advice!

Sean

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it's a .com domain and it expired jan 4th.

Answer (score 4):

If your domain name just expired, it's more than likely that you have some kind of renewal grace period.  Also, it's not uncommon for expired domain names to revert to a parking page.  Contact your registrar, and see what options are available for you.

Otherwise, if you have an objective trademark right to the domain name, that usually helps you retrieve it with minimal resistance.

If all else fails, you can turn to the [UDRP process](http://www.icann.org/en/udrp/udrp.htm) (Uniform Domain-Name Dispute-Resolution Policy). There's a fee upwards of $1000.00 associated with this, charged to both parties involved. So try your other options first.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is just to buy it back if its not too expensive.

The process for evicting a domain name squater is slow and tedious. This varies according to your top level domain if its a ".com" then ICANN has a procedure for reclaiming it.

However you will need a lawyer and ICANN is notoriously erratic in its judgements (the only consitent pattern is the party with the most money usually wins).

Worse if its a ".co.uk" domain the body which handles disputes, "NOMINET", is currently loaded with members who make a living from doamin name farming.

The Canadians probably have a fair and inexpensive procedure. :-)

Comment: Actually we probably have a system pandering to whatever the american lobby groups asked the minister responsible to do :P

Comment: James - check your facts.  There are indeed plenty of domainers in the .uk space, but they don't affect Nominet's DRS service which is relatively fast and inexpensive compared to a WIPO ruling.

Answer (score 1):

WIPO is the only organisation that can force ICANN to re-assign the domain name, I believe.

But that takes money and you have to prove ownership (such as trademark) as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get hold of the new registrator? (My contact information still appears in the WHOIS databases)

In that case the domain is still yours. 'WHOIS databases' do not cache information but gather it real-time.

> Is it possible to appeal to any authority to claim ownership?

No, because if the domain did expire, nobody 'snatched' it. They purchased the domain name according to the normal procedure. No point in claiming ownership if you're not the owner. Then again, if your details are still in WHOIS, you are likely still the owner.

> Is it possible to contact Google about removing the page from the search engines?

You could and they won't. Why would they? Again, the domain is owned by somebody who legitimately got it. Furthermore, if the domain did actually expire, that's nobody's fault but yours.